# How to let putty change its cursor shape accordingly?

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, readline, putty

When I use putty to log on to a bash shell, I want it like real term emulator in Linux. That means:
If I set shell to vi editing mode, the cursor would be a vertical line in inserting mode, and a block in a command mode.
How can I do this?

Thanks all you folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Also, it hasn't been updated in a while, so not sure asking the developer to add that functionality would help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there may be a way to do it through hacking readline. I have not tried it yet. Perhaps we could push for it to get mainstreamed?
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=106428

Apparently zsh has a similar hook built in according to this post that might be interesting to try:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=428452#p428452

Answer (score -1):

In the putty configuration, look under the 'Category' treeview, click on 'Window', there's a node underneath that called 'Appearance', Look at the cursor appearance on the right hand side pane of that dialog, check the box 'Cursor blinks'...then save that in your profile.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This just make the cursor blink, not change according to the bash mode change. Thanks all the same.